# Noisy HDD detected with 0,00Kb

Tags: hard-drive

I have a HDD that was connected to my pi. Yesterday the electricity company was shutting down the service for maitenance and when I came back from job I found out that it was not working. I plug the disk on the computer and I hear a noise (check the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvyYLC4BdY) to hear the noise). I changed the HDD to another box, just to make sure it was not box's fault. I plug it on the computer and I can see it (both on windows and Linux) but with 0,00kb. I tried with diskpart and several tools on windows, but couldnt make it work. My question is: Is this disk dead 100% or is recoverable?

BTW, I dont care about the data inside the disk

Thanks !

Comment: it seems the recovery will be more expensive than replace.

Comment: Well, I'm not planning to pay for recovery, that's why i ask here, to see if it's possible to fix it myself. And by the way, i do not want to recover the data.

Comment: While connecting HDD to computer, look how it is detected by BIOS. If it is not detected at all or detected with errors (wrong model name, wrong or zero size, etc.) its controller seems to be damaged. It is close to impossible to recover such problem "at home" except You have another HDD of this model/revision with mechanical damage and problemless controller.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already commented, it does not look good.

The noise indicates the disk is resetting itself over and over, trying to recalibrate. If it is visible to the computer but reports its total capacity as zero, it's how some disk models say "I'm failing my own internal self tests."

From the video you posted I can see that it's a Western Digital WD3200BEVT, manufactured in January 2008. You said it was a 1 TB disk, but according to the label, its capacity is just 320 GB??

Anyway, Western Digital has a specific diagnostic program: [Data Lifeguard Diagnostics](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=3&lang=en). You can try it and see what it says; it might have some vendor-specific commands that generic utilities won't have.

Generally, a 10-year old HDD is already past its expected end-of-life. If it lasted this long, you definitely got your money's worth off it in full. Don't waste time trying to fix it unless absolutely necessary for some reason.

Comment: you are right, is 320Gb, i confused it with other one. That tool I tried already with no luck :( So i will proceed to bury my poor disk.  Thanks all for the help.